# How is the order of tags defined for "Top Tags" in the "Profile"

Tags: support, tags

My "Top Tags" are not the ones with the highest score, but somehow the number of posts plays a rôle as well.

Can someone clarify the rules to me?

(by the way: Are they the same on all SE sites?)

EDIT: Top Tags

[image]

All Tags

[image]

You see that e.g. "lab-meeting" is missing in Top Tags.